# Angular Material 2 Tab Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to make an http call to the Facebook API when a tab is clicked (this is what the `getAlbum` method does). I tried adding a `(click)` attribute to the `mat-tab` element but it doesn't activate. This led me to putting a `(onSelect)` attribute on the `mat-group`, however the data I need is now out of scope.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="getAlbum(header.id)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let header of bachataAlbumHeaderNames" #albumId="header" label="{{header.name}}={{header.id}}">
    <div *ngFor="let image of bachataPicsArray; let i = index">

      <img flex (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event, i)" [ngClass]="hoveredId === i ? depth5: depth1" id="{{image.id}}" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)"
       class="gallery_pic" src="{{image.image}}" alt="Bachadiff Cardiff Bachata class picture of people enjoying the dance" />
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the indices of the tabs correspond to the `bachataAlbumHeaderNames` array, you can access the header id via the active tab index with the `selectedIndexChange` output event:

HTML template:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="getAlbum($event)">
```

Typescript class:

```typescript
getAlbum(tabId) {
  const headerId = this.bachataAlbumHeaderNames[tabId].id;
  // API calls...
}
```

I've created a [stackblitz example](https://angular-exejpe.stackblitz.io).